# Magento 2 can't store apostrophe in manufacturer options

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2

I tried to store a brand name with apostrophe like **"nature's way"**,  **"nature's answer"** to the option values of manufacturer attribute.  But Magento CE 2.2 always store the apostrophe " ' " of them to their ASCII value `&amp;#039;`.

Could the core team correct this error?  I know when you show the ASCII string to apostrophe, you need to use escapeHtml() function.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to programmatically use `$eavSetup->addAttributeOption` in a data install or upgrade script, where `$eavSetup` is an instance of `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup`.

When doing that, the apostrophe won't get converted to its HTML entity variant, and will be stored in the database as an apostrophe. However, you also would never be able to save the attribute in the admin, as it would then be converted to `&#039;`.

Other than that, not much can be done except for fixing that bug in Magento. I've created an issue on the official Github channel: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12127

I've also added a pull request here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12133

You can take that code and patch it yourself if you know how to. Otherwise wait for an official release that contains the bugfix.

Comment: The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.3.0 release.